# Python TypeError even though I am only working with int and float

Tags: python, error-handling

The code below runs fine in my test cases, but it results in the following errors when launch the program manually:

```
                    bm25 = tf * (k + 1)
                    bm25 = bm25 / (k * (1 - b + b * dl / avdl) + tf)
                    bm25 = bm25 * math.log(n/df, 2)


  File "inverted_index.py", line 116, in read_from_file
    bm25 = tf * (k + 1)
  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

All the symbols are variables (either float or int). I am not trying to do anything that involves strings. I just want to do the calculation...

The error propagates to the next line of the computation if I comment out the line that is causing the error:

```
                    # bm25 = tf * (k + 1)
                    bm25 = bm25 / (k * (1 - b + b * dl / avdl) + tf)
                    bm25 = bm25 * math.log(n/df, 2)



  File "inverted_index.py", line 117, in read_from_file
    bm25 = bm25 / (k * (1 - b + b * dl / avdl) + tf)
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Note bm25 is initialized to zero. Initially I did the whole computation in one line, but that was too long for my style checker.

I am new to python and I don't how to resolve this.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

The full code is quite long:

```
    def read_from_file(self, file_name, b, k):
    """
    >>> ii = InvertedIndex()
    >>> ii.read_from_file("example.txt", b=0, k="inf")
    >>> sorted(ii.inverted_lists.items())
    [('animated', [(1, 0.415), (2, 0.415), (4, 0.415)]), \
    ('animation', [(3, 2.0)]), ('film', [(2, 1.0), (4, 1.0)]), \
    ('movie', [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.0), (4, 0.0)]), \
    ('non', [(2, 2.0)]), \
    ('short', [(3, 1.0), (4, 2.0)])]

    """

    """
    >>> ii = InvertedIndex()
    >>> ii.read_from_file("example.txt", b=0.75, k=1.75)
    >>> sorted(ii.inverted_lists.items())
    [('animated', [(1, 0.459), (2, 0.402), (4, 0.358)]), \
    ('animation', [(3, 2.211)]), ('film', [(2, 0.969), (4, 0.863)]), \
    ('movie', [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.0), (4, 0.0)]), \
    ('non', [(2, 1.938)]), \
    ('short', [(3, 1.106), (4, 1.313)])]

    """

    dls = []
    avdl = 0

    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        record_id = 1
        for line in file:
            tf = 1
            line = line.strip()
            # Store the record as a tuple (title, description).
            self.records.append(tuple(line.split("\t")))

            dl = 0
            for word in re.split("[^A-Za-z]+", line):
                word = word.lower().strip()

                # Ignore the word if it is empty.
                if len(word) == 0:
                    continue
                dl = dl + 1
                if word not in self.inverted_lists:
                    # The word is seen for first time, create a new list.
                    tf = 1
                    self.inverted_lists[word] = [(record_id, tf)]
                elif self.inverted_lists[word][-1] == (record_id, tf):
                    tf = tf + 1
                    self.inverted_lists[word][-1] = (record_id, tf)
                    tf = 1
                elif self.inverted_lists[word][-1] != (record_id, tf):
                    # Make sure that the list contains the id at most once.
                    self.inverted_lists[word].append((record_id, tf))
            record_id += 1
            avdl = avdl + dl
            dls.append(dl)

        n = record_id - 1
        avdl = avdl / n
        bm25 = 0
        for key in self.inverted_lists:
            df = len(self.inverted_lists[key])
            counter = 0
            for value in self.inverted_lists[key]:
                counter = counter + 1
                tf = value[1]
                dl = dls[value[0] - 1]
                if k == "inf":
                    bm25 = tf * math.log(n/df, 2)
                else:
                    bm25 = float(tf) * (float(k) + float(1))
                    bm25 = bm25 / (float(k) * (float(1) - float(b)
                                               + float(b) * float(dl) /
                                               float(avdl)) + float(tf))
                    bm25 = bm25 * math.log(n/df, 2)
                self.inverted_lists[key][counter - 1] = (
                    self.inverted_lists[key][counter - 1][0],
                    round(bm25, 3))
```

`b` and `k` are provided by the user in this case by the test.

`tf` and `dl` are simple counters that keep track of how frequent words are in their respective documents.

`n`, `avdl` and `df` are also just metrics about the data that is being sorted.

The only variables that are being treated differently when I launch the program manually are `b` and `k`, because I (the user) am entering those values...

EDIT 2:

Thanks @N. Ivanov, the use of floats did solve this problem, but only when I used floats excessively:

```
                    bm25 = float(tf) * (float(k) + float(1))
                    bm25 = bm25 / (float(k) * (float(1) - float(b)
                                               + float(b) * float(dl) /
                                               float(avdl)) + float(tf))
                    bm25 = bm25 * math.log(n/df, 2)
```

Comment: can you provide the full code? I would say use `float()` around the problem area, what it does, it converts the type of the variable to float (only if it is a number)

Comment: How do you declare variables `tf` and `k`?

Comment: Looks like either `tf` or `k` is a string

Comment: If Python says something is a string then it __is__ a string without any possible doubt. IOW somewhere in the code that you didn't post, one of your variables that you think is a float or int is actually bound to a str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the source of the strings:

```
file_name = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
k = sys.argv[3]

ii = InvertedIndex()
ii.read_from_file(file_name, b, k)
```

My main method obtains the user input and passes it to my method. I didn't think it would interpret the user input as a string - I still have to get used to dynamic typing...

@all, thanks for helping!